# Daily quest "Destroy 40 minions" in Hearthstone

Tags: hearthstone

For the destroy minions quest, which minion deaths count towards my quest progress? For example, what about these cases?

- If I cast a spell that destroys an enemy minion.
- If I cast a spell that destroys my own minion (like Sacrificial Pact, or maybe even Power Overwhelming).
- If my minion attacks another minion and the other minion dies.
- If my minion attacks another minion and my minion dies.
- If another minion attacks my minion and the other minion dies.
- If another minion attacks my minion and my minon dies.

Comment: Haven't played for a while but I'm quite sure all these cases count.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quest is somewhat misleading in description. All that matters is that 40 enemy minions die. If the enemy uses Sacrificial Pact or Hellfire on his own minions, that counts as a minion kill for you. If you do the same, enemy minions count, but yours do not.

"Kill" in this case is anything that would trigger a deathrattle effect if the minion were not silenced and had deathrattle. This means that burning cards with Vanish or Sap counts, while burning cards with Coldlight Oracle would not.

Comment: But Vanish and Sap don't trigger deathrattles? I don't think returning cards to owner's hand counts.

Comment: @Moyli Only if it destroys the card: https://youtu.be/56tLx26t1Iw?t=50s

Comment: Ah I see, I missed the part that they'll get destroyed.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. What about tokens? I just Flamestrike'd a full board of whelps from Open the Gate, twice. And he lost a dozen others, didn't keep count. Quest counter went up +15.

Answer (score 1):

You have to kill enemy minions, your own don't count. So just simply reduce minion X's health to 0 and that counts as 1/40

Answer (score -2):

Kill enemy minions my any means, Spell or direct attack, it doesn't matters. But you killing your own wont count.